# Example of jqgrid with python

Tags: python, django, jqgrid

So I've cloned this

https://bitbucket.org/romildo/django-jqgrid-demo.git

as I am looking for a working example of jqgrid with django.

I've been updating the code (as this seems like it was written for a version 2 of django and I'm workng on 4.1)

I'm completely stumped by the lines

```
from jqgrid import JqGrid
```

giving me this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jqgrid'
```

I cannot find a reference to jqgrid within pip and I cannot install one (jqgrid is not a python package)

I understand that jqgrid is a javascript component around jquery but how do I get that to work in Python

I have google for django-jqgrid and on youtube. None of the answers provide enough information to get a simple working example up. There seems to be an assumption that everything is installed and I'd like to understand what is required where and how to reference

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can install this library:

```
pip install js.jqgrid
```

And now your above error will solve